# Different Criteria in WHERE CLAUSE in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I have five Parameters to check in MYSQL query.Here are these

```
1- price
2-Category
3-location
4-sublocation
5-beds
```

Now first two are must like this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE price>myprice1 AND price<myprice2 AND category=mycategory
```

For rest of three i have different case.here is general case

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE price>myprice1 AND price<myprice2 AND category=mycategory
AND location=mylocation AND sublocation=mysublocation AND beds=mybeds
```

IF this query do not give me result then i can remove beds like this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE price>myprice1 AND price<myprice2 AND category=mycategory
AND location=mylocation AND sublocation=mysublocation
```

I need atleast 10 result...if this query give me 5 results then i will remove sublocation but in result those five results must be on top.

Generally,to get my result i have to reduce ANDs but matching with previous/removed parameters result must be on top.

**UPDATED**

This is my query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE price>140000 AND price< 210000 AND category=1 AND location=2
```

I have this query now which give me 5 results so i want to remove last AND which will give me more result

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE price>140000 AND price< 210000 AND category=1
```

but now i want to show all those 5 records having location=2 on top

Comment: Seems like you should stick to the first query (but order it by beds, sublocation, etc.) and then use PHP to sort out the ones you need.

Comment: It's like as if you have no idea what you really need and you want to test through trial and error method. I don't know if this can be solved through query alone, but in PHP you could make an array of your `where` conditions. Execute the query with maximum conditions, check if you have 10 or more results, if not, take off the last where condition from the array and execute query again and so on. Now for those top five results...I think you need to provide some of your sample data.

Comment: Create your query in a subquery including the count of beds, the order the subquery by count of beds and take only the top ten.

Comment: It is quite clear,the first query give me result but i want to sort it by other three parameters ..thats it

Comment: @Shomz:Please check updated query

Comment: Alright, I'll give you an example. Do you have any ordering algorithm on location, or you just want to show it if it has any value?

Comment: No algorithm,just show my matched values on top then follow any order,does not matter